# Java datetime comparison per 15 minutes

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a csv records with timestamps like or every 5 minutes:

```
- 2015/05/19 16:15:00
- 2015/05/19 16:20:00
- 2015/05/19 16:35:00
- 2015/05/19 16:10:00
- 2015/05/19 16:55:00
```

I'm using an array to compare if the dates per record is within 15 minutes:

```
ArrayList<String> per15Min = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("00,15");
    add("15,30");
    add("30,45");
    add("45,00");
}};
```

What I do is read each record, split it based on "," to extract the Dates:

```
private SimpleDateFormat csvDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
private SimpleDateFormat fileDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");

// Loop thru each record
while ((perLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

    // Store date per record in a string
    String[] perColumn = perLine.split(",", -1);
    String date = perColumn[0];

    // Convert record date to yyyyMMddHHmm
    Date subDateP = csvDateFormat.parse(csvDate);
    String subDateF = fileDateFormat.format(subDateP);

    // Extract the date without the day (dd)
    String subDate = subDateF.substring(0,10);

    for (int j = 0 ; j < per15Min.size() ; j++) {
        String[] s = per15Min.get(j).split(",", -1);
        String m1 = s[0];
        String m2 = s[1];

        // All dates are in a yyyyMMddHHmm format
        Date before = fileDateFormat.parse(subDate + m1);
        Date after = fileDateFormat.parse(subDate + m2);
        Date csvRd = fileDateFormat.parse(date);

        System.out.println("DATE " + before + " : " + after + " : " + csvRd);

        // Having problems doing date comparison            
        if ((before.compareTo(csvRd) >= 0) && (csvRd.compareTo(after) < 0)) {
            System.out.println("DATE HERE" + before + " : " + after + " : " + csvRd);
        }


    }
}
```

As you can see based from the sysout it doesn't seem to work:

```
DATE HEREWed May 20 07:30:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:45:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:30:00 SGT 2015
DATE HEREWed May 20 07:30:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:45:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:25:00 SGT 2015
DATE HEREWed May 20 07:30:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:45:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:20:00 SGT 2015
DATE HEREWed May 20 07:30:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:45:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:15:00 SGT 2015
DATE HEREWed May 20 07:30:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:45:00 SGT 2015 : Wed May 20 07:10:00 SGT 2015
```

What I need is something like if the timestamp (per 5 min) is within the 15 minute array it will enter the condition:

```
00-10 minutes must enter at 00,15
15-25 minutes must enter at 15,30
30-40 minutes must enter at 30,45
45-55 minutes must enter at 45,00
```

Anyone knows whats wrong with the if condition?

Comment: Read the values in as `Date`, `LocalDateTime` values and use `equals`, `before`/`isBefore` and `after`/`isAfter`

Comment: Can you explain the output more carefully? It's unclear what you want to achieve because you mix IO and calculations...

Comment: Add the code that reads the file too.

Comment: Don't use strings. Use numbers and math. Parse the date once, then create a new date with the values of year, month, day, hour, calculated minute and 0 seconds. Calculate lower end with (getMinute()/15)*15 (will truncate to 0, 15, 30, 45) then +15mins for upper interval. Use LocalDateTime in Java 8 or even earlier prefer joda-time if possible. Can be done with Date converting to millis, but a bit hard to do the truncate.

Comment: The [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) project will help you with that [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you need to deal with date/time information, you should use an appropriate API, in your case you can get away with `Date` and `Calendar`, but it would be better to use Java 8's Time API if you can or Joda-Time, as the interactions are simpler then `Calendar`

Convert the `String` date values into `Date`s or (better yet) `LocalDateTime` values and make use of their comparison methods

- `Date#before`, `Date#after`, `Date#equals`
- `LocalDateTime#isBefore`, `LocalDateTime#isAfter`, `LocalDateTime#equals`

For example...

```
List<String> listOfDateValues = new ArrayList<>(25);
listOfDateValues.addAll(Arrays.asList(
                new String[]{"2015/05/19 16:10:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:00:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:05:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:10:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:15:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:20:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:25:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:30:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:35:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:40:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:45:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:50:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:55:00",
                    "2015/05/19 16:25:00"}));

List<String> per15Min = new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(
                                new String[]{
                                    "00,15",
                                    "16,30",
                                    "31,45",
                                    "46,59" //??
                                }
                )
);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Map<String, List<String>> mapGroups = new HashMap<>();
for (String dateValue : listOfDateValues) {

    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(dateValue, formatter);
    for (String range : per15Min) {
        String[] split = range.split(",");
        LocalDateTime startRange = ldt.withMinute(Integer.parseInt(split[0])).withSecond(0).withNano(0);
        LocalDateTime endRange = ldt.withMinute(Integer.parseInt(split[1])).withSecond(59).withNano(999999999);
        if ((ldt.equals(startRange) || ldt.isAfter(startRange))
                        && (ldt.equals(endRange) || ldt.isBefore(endRange))) {
            List<String> group = mapGroups.get(range);
            if (group == null) {
                group = new ArrayList<String>(25);
                mapGroups.put(range, group);
            }
            group.add(dateValue);
        }
    }

}

for (String range : per15Min) {
    List<String> group = mapGroups.get(range);
    System.out.println(range);
    for (String dateValue : group) {
        System.out.println(" -> " + dateValue);
    }
}
```

Which outputs...

```
00,15
 -> 2015/05/19 16:10:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:00:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:05:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:10:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:15:00
16,30
 -> 2015/05/19 16:20:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:25:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:30:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:25:00
31,45
 -> 2015/05/19 16:35:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:40:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:45:00
46,59
 -> 2015/05/19 16:50:00
 -> 2015/05/19 16:55:00
```

Note, I've modified your rangers, it makes no sense to have a range of `00-15` AND `15-30`...where does a time of `xx:15.00` go?  Into both sets?

Comment: Your ranges are also problematic if there is ever a non-zero second entry on an edge case.

Comment: @doogabides Trying to keep it simple. BRB

Comment: @doogabides Updated the ranges to min/max values

Comment: Although this answer works, I think it's simply an ugly way to use strings (there are a lot of corner-cases like what if a culture does not use arabic numbers, the year is after `9999`, etc.), and using string manipulation in general to do data manipulation is in general a bad idea. Not complaining about the answer itself. Furthermore this is a brute-force approach that is definitely not easy to modify. More on the fact that it encourages people to write bad code...

Comment: @CommuSoft How so? The intention is to take a `String` set of data (which was the prescribed input of the OP) into a format which can be manipulated. It's more of an example of "how" to do something, rather then the "way" to do something.  By using an appropriate Time based library, hopeful we deal with many of the issues related to *" does not use arabic numbers, the year is after 9999, etc."* - ie "I have this chunk of data and I need these results" - this deals with the middle part of the problem, the translation from one context to another

Answer (score 2):

The code you provide, shows a lot of *bad smells* (or *anti-patterns*): patterns computer scientists have found out through experience that cause a lot of problems.

The most problematic is that you rely on string formatting and parsing.

> Only use strings for *text*, not as some *intermediate representation* of all kinds of data like *tuples*, *Date*'s, etc.

Especially for culture dependent concepts like Date's this can result in total chaos. For instance it is possible that some culture doesn't write dates using Arabic numbers (like `12`), but for instance uses Roman numbers (like `XII`). Or perhaps at some point in time the year will not be representable anymore with four digits, or one parses the date with timezone `12:15:57 UTC+01`, but the timezone is lost during formatting and parsing. In general it is a **bad idea to do data processing using string processing**, only do this if the data is text/names/strings/...

Next you seem to store multiples of `15`, which is a bit unusefull. It will slow down the process.

> Don't store multiples, etc. explicitly and only use *brute force approaches* (where you enumerate over the elements if absolutely necessary.

In this answer I propose two methods: `dateFloor(Date d, int m)` and `dateCeil(Date d, int m)`. You can pass the number of minutes - in this case `15` as an extra parameter to set the granularity.

```
public static Date dateFloor (Date d, int m) {
    Date d2 = (Date) d.clone();
    d2.setMinutes((d2.getMinutes()/m)*m);
    return d2;
}

public static Date dateCeil (Date d, int m) {
    Date d2 = (Date) d.clone();
    d2.setMinutes(((d2.getMinutes()+m)/m)*m);
    //alternatively: d2.setMinutes((d2.getMinutes()/m)*m+m);
    return d2;
}
```

The `DateFloor` can calculate the `before` date and analogue the `DateCeil` calculate the `after` date.

Using these methods, the method is as simple as:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    Date date = csvDateFormat.parse(line);
    Date before = dateFloor(date,15);
    Date after = dateCeil(date,15);
    System.out.print(before);
    System.out.print(" <= ");
    System.out.print(date);
    System.out.print(" < ");
    System.out.println(after);
 }
```

Only two lines are used to implement the *business logic*...

You can find an online [*Ideone* demo here](http://ideone.com/ibgKuI).

I didn't do the `csv` parsing, so you still have to split on the comma and extract the first part. But that's not the vital part.

For your given input - without the dashes (`-`) - it gives the following output:

```
Tue May 19 16:15:00 GMT 2015 <= Tue May 19 16:15:00 GMT 2015 < Tue May 19 16:30:00 GMT 2015
Tue May 19 16:15:00 GMT 2015 <= Tue May 19 16:20:00 GMT 2015 < Tue May 19 16:30:00 GMT 2015
Tue May 19 16:30:00 GMT 2015 <= Tue May 19 16:35:00 GMT 2015 < Tue May 19 16:45:00 GMT 2015
Tue May 19 16:00:00 GMT 2015 <= Tue May 19 16:10:00 GMT 2015 < Tue May 19 16:15:00 GMT 2015
Tue May 19 16:45:00 GMT 2015 <= Tue May 19 16:55:00 GMT 2015 < Tue May 19 17:00:00 GMT 2015
```

## Other errors

A conceptual error you've made is that when you format the date as a string, and you try to generate the last `15` minutes part, it will append `00` to it resulting in a **time lower than the actual time**, because your method does not increment the hours first.

## Additional advice

You mix I/O with methods that calculate something. The *controller* pattern says you must split these concerns. Furthermore you better use a csv parser. If you use strings like `"foo,bar",baz` in a `.csv` file, you will split between `foo` and `bar`. That's not according to the standards.

Comment: FYI: `Date#setMinutes` is deprecated.  Better to use Java 8's Time API, JodaTime or if you're really stuck, `Calendar`

Comment: @MadProgrammer: true, but the question itself uses `Date`. Will update with a comment about it.

Comment: The question was also using `String` manipulation for it's time comparisons, which we can both agree is a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

Answers I received are all great but the server I'm gonna deploy this has only the java version of 1.5 so as much as possible i dont use many API libraries as some is not compatible.

Basically I found a solution:

```
while ((perLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

    // Split row per column
    String[] perColumn = perLine.split(",", -1);

    // Convert unix date to yyyyMMddHHmm
    java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(perColumn[0]) * 1000);

    String csvDateNoDay = fileDateFormat.format(time).substring(0,10);
    long csvDateYsDay = fileDateFormat.parse(fileDateFormat.format(time)).getTime();

    // Date of the file to be created/used
    String fileDate = "";
    String fileUnixDate = "";

    for (int j = 0 ; j < per15Min.size() ; j++) {
        String[] s = per15Min.get(j).split(",", -1);
        long isBeforeDate = fileDateFormat.parse(csvDateNoDay + s[0]).getTime();
        long isAfterDate = fileDateFormat.parse(csvDateNoDay + s[1]).getTime();

        /* Compare the Date for each record versus the list of array:
         * Record (Minutes) Array  Filename Date
         *     00 - 14       00    yyyyMMddHH00
         *     15 - 29       15    yyyyMMddHH15
         *     30 - 44       30    yyyyMMddHH30
         *     45 - 59       45    yyyyMMddHH45
         */     
        if ((csvDateYsDay>isBeforeDate && csvDateYsDay<isAfterDate) || csvDateYsDay==isBeforeDate) { 
            fileDate = csvDateNoDay + s[0];
            fileUnixDate = String.valueOf(isBeforeDate);
        }    
    }
}
```

The fileDate and fileDateUnix Strings will have the correct date which will be used to name the new csv files and to split each recod based on the timestamp per 15 minutes.